# How to read files (json) from the container of the cosmos db using python code

Tags: json, python-3.x, azure-cosmosdb

### I want to get the json file from the container and change it accordingly and save it in json format. i have the read only access to cosmos db

below is the image of cosmos db
[image]

i am getting this error

CosmosResourceNotFoundError

```
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient
    endpoint = '' ##i have hidden it because it is confidential
    key='' ##i have hidden it because it is confidential
    client = CosmosClient(endpoint, key)
    database_name  = 'DATA'
    container_name = 'TenantInfo'
    database = client.get_database_client(database_name)
    container = database.get_container_client(container_name)
    query = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.partitionKey = 'UPITT' and c.id = 'Org.OrgUnit.UPITT'"
    items = container.query_items(query, enable_cross_partition_query=True)
    for i in items:
        print(i)
```

i tried the above code

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because you are using incorrect database and container name in your code. Based on the screenshot, the name of the database is `TenantInfo` and the name of the container is `Meta`.

Please make these changes and then you should not get the error you are getting.